# Circular dependency in the class constructor

Tags: python-3.x, constructor, circular-dependency

I have the following class:

```
class CustomDictionary(dict):
    def __init__(self, val, *args, **kwargs):
        self.wk = val
        super(dict, self).__init__()

    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        if key in self.wk:
            raise Exception("Wrong key", "")

        key = key.replace(" ", "_")
        self.__dict__[key] = value


def main():
    wrong_keys = ("r23", "fwfew", "s43t")

    dictionary = CustomDictionary(wrong_keys)

    dictionary["a1"] = 1
```

As you can see, I create the attribute `wk` in the `constructor`. But I have `__setattr__` function, in which I work with attribute `wk`. However, `CustomDictionary object` has no attribute `wk`.

Comment: super(dict, self).__init__() sould also be super(dict, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`__setattr__` is a pain that way, because it is called for every assignment to an instance member.  Probably the easiest fix for your situation is to define an empty `wk` before `__init__`:

```
class CustomDictionary(dict):

    wk = []

    def __init__(self, val, *args, **kwargs):
        self.wk = val
        ...
```

Comment: But, won't all the instances of CustomDictionary end up having the exact same self.wk if you do this?

Comment: @Apero: Good question! In this case, no, because `wk` is replaced in `__init__`, not mutated.

Comment: Okay, to be strictly accurate, a new `wk` is being added to the instance, shadowing the class `wk` -- again, because of the direct assignment.  If the line had read `self.wk[:] = ...` then it would have changed the class `wk`, and all instances would see the same list.